# Python Datetime problem: Is There a better solution

Tags: python, function, datetime

I found the correct solution to the following problem which uses python 3 datetime objects. However, my solution seems really messy and I was wondering if I could get some help to clean it up:

Question:
Complete the which_date() function below which returns the day that follows a specified time period after an initial date. Time periods can be specified in two different ways: as a number of days like "1 day" or "30 days", or as a number of weeks like "2 weeks" or "12 weeks".

```
def which_date(start_date,time):
    """
    This function takes as input a string depicting a date in YYYY/mm/dd
    format and a string stating a time period in the form of "X day(s)" or
    "Y week(s)". Output should be a string in form YYYY/mm/dd with the date
    that is X days or Y weeks after the initial date.
    """

    # Every thing after this comment and before 'return end_date' is my 
    #code to solve this probmem
    start_date_split = start_date.split('/')
    start_date_split = list(map(int, start_date_split))
    year, month, day = start_date_split[0], start_date_split[1], 
    start_date_split[2]
    start_date_date_obj = datetime.date(year, month, day)

    time_split = time.split(' ')
    time_amount = int(time_split[0])
    days_or_weeks = time_split[1]

    time_to_add = datetime.timedelta(0)
    if 'day' in days_or_weeks:
        time_to_add = datetime.timedelta(days = time_amount)
    else:
        time_to_add = datetime.timedelta(weeks = time_amount)

    end_date_date_obj = start_date_date_obj + time_to_add    
    end_date = end_date_date_obj.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    return end_date
```

The following is the verification test:

```
def test():
   assert which_date('2016/02/10','35 days') == '2016/03/16'
   assert which_date('2016/12/21','3 weeks') == '2017/01/11'
   assert which_date('2015/01/17','1 week') == '2015/01/24'
   print("All tests completed.")
```

Comment: Look at `datetime` format conversions; they should be able to cut out a few lines of ugly split/int/etc.

Comment: `start_date_date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y/%m/%d')` is the obvois thing i see (as mentioned by Prune).

Comment: This question might be appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Did some list destructuring to cut down on some lines of code. Also removed the creation of some new variables and just used the values directly:

```
import datetime

def which_date(start_date,time):
  """
  This function takes as input a string depicting a date in YYYY/mm/dd
  format and a string stating a time period in the form of "X day(s)" or
  "Y week(s)". Output should be a string in form YYYY/mm/dd with the date
  that is X days or Y weeks after the initial date.
  """

  # Every thing after this comment and before 'return end_date' is my 
  # code to solve this problem

  year, month, day = [int(each) for each in start_date.split('/')]

  start_date_date_obj = datetime.date(year, month, day)

  time_amount, days_or_weeks = [int(value) if index==0 else value for index, value in enumerate(time.split(' '))]

  time_to_add = datetime.timedelta(days = time_amount) if days_or_weeks=='days' else datetime.timedelta(weeks = time_amount)

  return (start_date_date_obj + time_to_add).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

def test():
  assert which_date('2016/02/10','35 days') == '2016/03/16'
  assert which_date('2016/12/21','3 weeks') == '2017/01/11'
  assert which_date('2015/01/17','1 week') == '2015/01/24'
  print("All tests completed.")

test()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in order to have a 'cleaner' function:

```
import re
import datetime


def which_date(start_date, time):
    # Split your date into a list by using non-decimal characters as separators
    year, month, day = re.split(r'\D', start_date)
    start_date_date_obj = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))

    # Create group captures in order to get the quantity of day(s)/week(s)
    # and pass those as generic arguments to timedelta
    time_match = re.search(r'(\d+) (day|week)[s]?', time)
    args = {time_match.group(2) + 's': int(time_match.group(1))}
    time_to_add = datetime.timedelta(**args)

    end_date_date_obj = start_date_date_obj + time_to_add
    end_date = end_date_date_obj.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    return end_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more simple version [of a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53327783/1531971). I'm a beginner so I can't understand all of the advanced code here.

```
import datetime
def which_date(start_date,time):
    """
    This function takes as input a string depicting a date in YYYY/mm/dd
    format and a string stating a time period in the form of "X day(s)" or
    "Y week(s)". Output should be a string in form YYYY/mm/dd with the date
    that is X days or Y weeks after the initial date.
    """

    year, month, day = [int(each) for each in start_date.split('/')]


    start_date_date_obj = datetime.date(year, month, day)

    add = 1
    string = time.split()
    if string[1] == "days" or string[1] == "day":
        add = int(string[0])
    else:
        add = (int(string[0]))*7



    time_to_add = datetime.timedelta(days = add)

    end_date = (start_date_date_obj + time_to_add).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

    return end_date
```